# SOLVED CiviMobile: DB Error in adding a Participant to an Event

Tags: error, database, civimobile

I have an issue with the database for which I find no solution, even after intensive search on Internet.
It now unables me to add a Participant to an Event. And even has consequences on adding Relationship or Memberships.
Could you kindly help to solve this?
Thanks for your help.
Drupal 7.69
CiviCRM 5.21.1

Below are the logs

```
Feb 28 11:13:28  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -19
    [message] => DB Error: no such field
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , message , entity_table , entity_id ) VALUES ( 509 , 'Array' , '%display_name has created participant.' , 'Participant' ,  1677 )  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'data' in 'field list']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , message , entity_table , entity_id ) VALUES ( 509 , 'Array' , '%display_name has created participant.' , 'Participant' ,  1677 )  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'data' in 'field list']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , message , entity_table , entity_id ) VALUES ( 509 , 'Array' , '%display_name has created participant.' , 'Participant' ,  1677 )  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'data' in 'field list']"]
)


Feb 28 11:13:28  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(192): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(987): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , m...")
#3 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , m...")
#4 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , m...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1920): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , m...", "1054 ** Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'")
#7 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1229): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , m...")
#9 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2416): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , m...")
#10 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1040): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data , m...")
#11 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(554): DB_DataObject->insert()
#12 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/BAO/PushNotificationMessages.php(20): CRM_Core_DAO->save()
#13 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/BAO/PushNotificationMessages.php(40): CRM_CiviMobileAPI_BAO_PushNotificationMessages::add((Array:7))
#14 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/PushNotification/SaveMessageHelper.php(29): CRM_CiviMobileAPI_BAO_PushNotificationMessages::create((Array:7))
#15 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/PushNotification/Utils/BasePushNotificationManager.php(59): CRM_CiviMobileAPI_PushNotification_SaveMessageHelper::saveMessages((Array:1), 1677, "Participant", "Soirée Dansante Mars 2020", "%display_name has created participant.", (Array:3))
#16 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/civimobileapi.php(332): CRM_CiviMobileAPI_PushNotification_Utils_BasePushNotificationManager->sendNotification()
#17 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(298): civimobileapi_civicrm_post("create", "Participant", 1677, Object(CRM_Event_BAO_Participant))
#18 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/DrupalBase.php(74): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:72), "civicrm_post", 4, "create", "Participant", 1677, Object(CRM_Event_BAO_Participant), NULL, NULL)
#19 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(98): CRM_Utils_Hook_DrupalBase->invokeViaUF(4, "create", "Participant", 1677, Object(CRM_Event_BAO_Participant), NULL, NULL, "civicrm_post")
#20 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(184): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent), "hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))
#21 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(46): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:2), "hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent))
#22 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(47): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent))
#23 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(392): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent))
#24 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/BAO/Participant.php(129): CRM_Utils_Hook::post("create", "Participant", 1677, Object(CRM_Event_BAO_Participant))
#25 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/BAO/Participant.php(181): CRM_Event_BAO_Participant::add((Array:15))
#26 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration.php(853): CRM_Event_BAO_Participant::create((Array:15))
#27 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration.php(695): CRM_Event_Form_Registration::addParticipant(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "509")
#28 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.php(637): CRM_Event_Form_Registration->confirmPostProcess("509", NULL)
#29 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(479): CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm->postProcess()

#30 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(144): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#31 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(45): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "next", "Next")
#32 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "next")
#33 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Confirm), "next")
#34 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(335): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#35 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(268): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#36 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#37 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#38 /home/leboucli/activites/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(456): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#39 /home/leboucli/activites/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("event", "register")
#40 /home/leboucli/activites/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#41 {main}
```

[SOLVED]
This issue was solved by installing a new extension, as Jon G - Megaphone Tech suggests below.
Thanks @Jon G - Megaphone Tech for the very useful help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is related to the CiviMobile extension - you can see it mentioned in the backtrace, and the table with the error, `civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages`, is created by the CiviMobile extension.

The error is that there's a field in that database table which is missing called `data`.  I can see from the [CiviMobile source code](https://github.com/agiliway/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/blob/5d5c08fd7d564dc07e6ac5a10d48b2a8ceb5048f/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/Upgrader.php#L83) that this field was added with Version 5.0.  Is it possible that you installed the upgrade but didn't run the database upgrade?  Go to **Administer menu » Administration Console » System Status** and see if there's a message telling you to run the database upgrades.

If the database upgrade ran but failed, you might be in your current situation.  In that case, you'll need to run the following query on your MySQL database.  I copied the query from the link above, which is the upgrade code.

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages ADD data varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
```

UPDATE: Based on the comments below, it seems clear that the issue is with `log_civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages`, not `civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages`.  This is a bug in the CiviMobile upgrade routine (though a common one).  The trick is to run `CRM_Logging_Schema->fixSchemaDifferences`.  The easiest way to do this is to install or enable an extension that's not currently installed; you can uninstall it immediately afterward.

Comment: Thanks @Jon G - Megaphone Tech for your quick answer. I had a look at the SQL table and the `Data` field is allready there. Nevertheless I ran the SQL command. But it just confirmed that the field is existing.
`Requête SQL :

ALTER TABLE civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages ADD data varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL

MySQL a répondu : Documentation
#1060 - Nom du champ 'data' déjà utilisé`
What can I look at now to try and solve this issue ?

Comment: @WebmasterduBouclier Do you have advanced logging turned on?  If so, can you see if `log_civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages`is missing the `data` field?

Comment: Hi @Jon G - Megaphone Tech. 
I ran the following SQL command ``show create table log_civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages``
Here's the result :

Comment: ``CREATE TABLE `log_civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `contact_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `entity_table` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `entity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `send_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_read` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
 `invoke_contact_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `message_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `log_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,``

Comment: ``
 `log_conn_id` varchar(17) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `log_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `log_action` enum('Initialization','Insert','Update','Delete') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci``

Comment: And for total information the same on ``show create table civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages;`` gives
``CREATE TABLE `civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `contact_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `entity_table` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `entity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `send_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `is_read` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
``

Comment: `` `invoke_contact_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `message_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `data` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `FK_civicrm_contact_push_notification_message` (`contact_id`),
 KEY `INDEX_message` (`message`),
 KEY `INDEX_entity_table` (`entity_table`),
 KEY `INDEX_entity_record_id` (`entity_id`),
 KEY `INDEX_send_date` (`send_date`),
 KEY `INDEX_is_read` (`is_read`),
 KEY `INDEX_invoke_contact_id` (`invoke_contact_id`),``

Comment: `` CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_contact_push_notification_message` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59410 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci```

Comment: @WebmasterduBouclier It's very hard to read this as a comment.  Could you please edit your question to include this information?

Comment: Searching through these comments, it seems that the `data` field is indeed missing from the log.  I updated my answer with something new to try.