# 'DB Error: no such field' for all (free) event registrations

Tags: civievent, error

Using CiviCRM 5.20.2 on Drupal 7.69.

Having a new error whenever someone tries to register for an event through CiviEvent on our website. This happens for all events: private or public; those with custom fields and those with no custom fields; with confirmation screens turned on or off; with thank you emails turned on or off. The event is free/no payment processing.

The user sees this screen:

[image: DB Error: no such field]

The registration does not pull through on the back-end either.

This is the error message in the error log:

```
$Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => handle ) [code] => -19 [message] => DB Error: no
such field [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => INSERT INTO
civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data ,
message , entity_table , entity_id ) VALUES ( 6820 , 'Array' ,
'%display_name has created participant.' , 'Participant' , 2699 )
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'] [type] =>
DB_Error [user_info] => INSERT INTO
civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data ,
message , entity_table , entity_id ) VALUES ( 6820 , 'Array' ,
'%display_name has created participant.' , 'Participant' , 2699 )
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'] [to_string]
=> [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO
civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages (contact_id , data ,
message , entity_table , entity_id ) VALUES ( 6820 , 'Array' ,
'%display_name has created participant.' , 'Participant' , 2699 )
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'data' in 'field list']"] )
```

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SOLVED CiviMobile: DB Error in adding a Participant to an Event](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34907/solved-civimobile-db-error-in-adding-a-participant-to-an-event)

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech I fixed it by upgrading to Civi 5.23, but that thread seems relevant as well. Should I accept the edit in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading to Civi 5.23

However this may also be relevant: [SOLVED CiviMobile: DB Error in adding a Participant to an Event](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34907/solved-civimobile-db-error-in-adding-a-participant-to-an-event)

Comment: Any action that causes the advanced logging schema to be checked - upgrading CiviCRM, installing or enabling an extension, etc. will fix this problem.  Arguably it should be happening on extension upgrade to avoid this issue - I don't have time to write that patch but it would be fairly simple.